# Does froyo support AKASATANA and Yomigana based contact sorting?

Tags: android, unicode, localization, contacts, android-2.2-froyo

Can anyone tell me about the Japanese phonebook sorting status in
Android contacts?

Does froyo support AKASATANA and Yomigana?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean standard Froyo version of AOSP contact, probably it does not support that feature. Because I have HTC Magic/CyanogenMod 6 which is based on Froyo/AOSP. But its Contact has no field for Yomigana.

If you mean some specific JDM Android phone, it may depends on the model. Because such phone may have modified version of Contact.